# IDK what i did but i was fixing the timing chain on a 08 Ford escape 3.0 liter i went to crank it by hand it moves maybe 180°

Tags: ford, escape, timing-chain

Are you supposed do loosen the camshaft bolts? How are the a sprockets supposed to be set?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If it will only turn 180° this seems to me the engine is out of time and a piston and valve are coming into contact.